# Python - TypeError: 'float' object is not callable for print

Tags: python, typeerror

I am newbie into python programming. I have seen this error in stack overflow and read thourgh explanation...but I am doing simple thing and still getting that error...

```
def minMonthlyPayment(monthlyRate, previousBalance):
    minMonthlyPayment = monthlyRate * previousBalance
    return minMonthlyPayment

balance = 5000
monthlyRate = 0.05

for i in range(0, 12):
    print('Month: ', i)
    minMonthlyPayment = minMonthlyPayment(monthlyRate, balance)
    print('Minimum monthly payment: ', minMonthlyPayment)
```

can somebody suggest resolution and specially why some background of how python do it?

Comment: You have used the same variable name to recieve the value `minMonthlyPayment`. That is overwriting the function. Change the variable name and you should be fine

Comment: Function and variable have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
minMonthlyPayment = minMonthlyPayment(monthlyRate, balance)
```

you are binding the result to a name that is the same as your function. Try

```
minMonPay = minMonthlyPayment(monthlyRate, balance)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable name for both your return value and a function name.

```
minMonthlyPayment = minMonthlyPayment(monthlyRate, balance)
       ^                  ^
      These two are the same
```

Change one of the two to something different and adjust either your function definition to account for the changed name, or the `print` statement to use the new variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, `minMonthlyPayment` is bound to a function. However, the first time through the loop, you assign the return value of the function to the same name. The second time through the loop, you are essentially trying to call a `float` as a function, e.g.

```
(4.3)(monthlyRate, balance)
```

Pick a different name for the result of calling `minMonthlyPayment`

```
payment = minMonthlyPayment(monthlyRate, balance).
```

---

Also, use `this_style` instead of `thisStyle` for names other than class names.